# How to return the smallest average within a nested loop

Tags: python, function, loops, nested, minimum

I need to return the smallest average value of word similarities within a list (which I can do) but I don't know how to assign a word string value to the average values, for example in a list `['my', 'bro', 'myline']` of course bro would have the least word comparison value and hence I need `'bro'` to be returned along with the comparison value (which I already know how to...just need to know how to assign values within nested loops).

```
final_tup = ()
ave_list = []
for word in final_list:
    word1 = word
    sum = 0
    for word in final_list:
        word2 = word
        if word2 != word1:
            num = cossim(word1,word2)
            sum = sum + num
    average = float(sum/(len(final_list)-1))
    ave_list.append(average)
```

Comment: `just need to know how to assign values within nested loops` assign to where? what exactly are you missing, your code seems [though not very neat] almost complete. Sorry, but I fail to understand what exactly are you asking :\

Comment: In terms of the not-neatness: You should just do `for word1 in final_list` and `for word2 in final_list` instead of looping over `word` and then assigning. You should also probably just do `sum += cossim(word1, word2)` instead of what you're currently doing.

Comment: as in for each word1 that is being compared..I want to have that word to be assigned or be associated with its AVERAGE comparison value..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from operator import itemgetter

# Make the word list.
word_list = ['my', 'bro', 'myline'] 

# Do your code here to create ave_list

# Fetch the min index and min value of ave_list
min_index, minvalue = min(enumerate(ave_list), key = itemgetter(1) )

# Now get the word at the same min index location.
min_word = word_list[min_index]
```

Comment: Wait bro for this.. what happens when we have two index of the same minimum value? How do we print more than one word into the output?

Comment: For example if index 1 and 11 had the same minimum average value.. how do I output both of these words?

Comment: I can modify it tomorrow, but one good way will be to switch to use NumPy arrays for storing the averages.